What does the cable dangling on the rear left of my 2011 Hyundai Santa Fe do?
There's a cable dangling from the left rear of my Hyundai Santa Fe. What does it do? Is that a hazard to have it dangling like that?


That's where the Santa Fe has its trailer electrical connector. I can't see the end of the cable, but you should find a connector on the end with a rubber weather seal. If you get under and wire-tie the hanging cable to something solid, it won't be a hazard.
Also, it would be good to return the rubber grommet to the hole that it came from. It serves to keep water out of the hole that the cable emerges from, and prevent rubbing that could wear through the insulation.
If you recently drove over a downed branch or similar, it could have snagged the cable and pulled the grommet out, which is why it's dangling now. You may be able to neaten it up without wire ties by stuffing the cable back in the hole before you reinstall the grommet.
